# Nexus 5 Media Queries?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I am trying to write a mobile site for college using CSS media queries, however when I try to target the Nexus 5 using:

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 20em)
```

(Remember 20em = 320px) it doesn't work and instead fills the page roughly 90% on the X and Y axis.

The Viewport I am using is so:

```
<meta content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
```

I was thinking of writing a media query based on pixel ratio, but failed to find any answers via Google as to the ratio of the N5.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: 20em does not necessarily equal 320px. Em units are relative to the font being used.

Comment: Ok I've changed this, still encountering the issue though. Thanks!

Comment: Ideally you should not be targeting specific devices, but instead doing it for your design, so the site looks great at any size. Test it by resizing your browser.

Comment: The width of the Google Nexus 5 is 1080 pixels and the Nexus 5 has a pixel ratio of 1:3 so it is 360px and not 320px because 360 * 3 = 1080.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this viewport, setting the initial scale will prevent zooming. You can set your media query to around 767px (this will cover pretty much all mobile phones)... 768 gets you into tablet portrait views. With some crafty CSS (using percentages for your layout) your site should function great across all phones

```
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

Comment: 767? I thought most mobiles had their user agent set to pick up Media Queries at 320px.. at least both my Lumia and now Nexus had that...?

Comment: a lot of phones exceed 320px width these days, plus the browsers read your css pretty much like your computer and will treat media queries the same way. making sure your device doesnt try and scale anything by setting a proper viewport tag will give you a nice uniform look across a variety of smartphones, i use a viewport of maxwidth 1024/minwidth 768 for tablets and less then 767 for all phones and its worked liked a charm thus far

Answer (score 4):

The Nexus 5 device width is actually 360, or 22.5em based on 16px.

What I normally do is after 767px (1px less than most tablets) I switch to percent based, single column layouts to accommodate all the one off devices. I'll then set my browser window, and/or test on the device if I have it, at each popular viewport and fix any one off issues.

This approach is geared more for my work environment, which is very production oriented; we don't get a lot of time per site.

Answer (score 4):

With this media query you can catch the **Google Nexus 5**:

```
@media only screen 
and (min-width: 360px)
and (orientation: portrait)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3.0) {
  * {
    background-color: black;
  }
}
```

For safe handling of the specified width, the following should be placed in the `<head>` section of the HTML document:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no,initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
```